# Why extend a function with an empty object?

Tags: javascript

I was looking at the [Rebound javascript code](http://facebook.github.io/rebound/rebound-js/docs/rebound.html) and saw that the `SpringSystem` function is being extended with an empty object.

```
var SpringSystem = rebound.SpringSystem = function SpringSystem() {
    this._springRegistry = {};
    this._activeSprings = [];
    this._listeners = [];
    this._idleSpringIndices = [];
    this._boundFrameCallback = bind(this._frameCallback, this);
};

extend(SpringSystem, {});
```

Where `extend` looks like:

```
function extend(target, source) {
    for (var key in source) {
        if (source.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
            target[key] = source[key];
        }
    }
}
```

What does the first `extend` achieve by extending an empty object? It's my understanding that an empty object has no `hasOwnProperty(key)` for anything.

What am I missing?

Comment: My answer would be that this function serve the purpose to "transform" this function into an object by copying javascript's `proto`. I am not sure but that would be to me the only goal of this line.

Comment: I'm not sure that makes sense to me. My experience in node is that an empty object doesn't have any of its own properties. Could this be different in the browser?

Comment: Indeed the code does nothing. My guess is that it is just a place holder for future modifications of the code, so that if ever additional members should be added to the object, it should happen there.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing nothing, the code serves no purpose. It looks like a leftover from a class template, notice that other classes and all prototypes use this pattern.

That's also why [it has been removed in 2014](https://github.com/facebook/rebound-js/commit/b038a662cba97ca98715d48e6c51d9cd1feeb719#diff-fe7cb5d36ecc2db722fb8069142c7294L137).

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. I was beginning to doubt I'd learned anything at all when seeing this the first time.